# Meaning of argument in express.json({ extended: false})

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working with express to set up an API, and I came across this line of code: `app.use(express.json( { extended: false } ));`

I've seen the documentation from express, but I didn't find this method, is the documentation lacking or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers come from looking at the actual Express and body-parser code...

If you go look at the Express code for the `express.json()` method [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L78), you can see that it is a direct pass-through of the `.json()` method from the body-parser module.

```
 // from express.js
 exports.json = bodyParser.json;
```

So, if you then go look at the body-parser doc, there is nothing there for the `extended` option for the `body-parser.json()` middleware.

As you have discovered, the `extended` option is documented for the `body-parser.urlencoded()` middleware.  But, since that is different than the `.json()` middleware method, it appears that this code is mistaken to be using the `extended` option with the `.json()` middleware.

If you go look at the [code for the `body-parser.json()` middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js#L50), you will find no references at all to the `extended` option in the code.

So, it appears to be an option that is mistakenly passed in the code you show and is subsequently ignored by the express/body-parser json middleware.

Comment: @MiguelLuís - Yeah, the beauty of open source is you can always just go look at the code itself and get your answers.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer, although it is a weird one.
Somehow this line of code works, even though it takes in an option from a different method.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded

> This option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false) or the qs library (when true). The “extended” syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

You are not. This seems clearly to be a mistake. As [options] you can pass the following: inflate, limit, reviver, strict, type, verify

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Comment: I thought so, thanks! I've found the answer at random.